# How does a random seed work in a function factory in Python?

Tags: python, random, seed

Suppose I want to generate a bunch of binary number generators given the success probabilities. One concern I have is about the random seed. The random seeds for f1, f2, f3 are their creation time, right? And the seeds are fixed for each function regardless of the random seed in the global namespace, right?

```
def f(p):
    import random, time
    random.seed(time.time())
    def g():
        return 1 if random.random() < p else 0
    return g

f1 = f(0.05)
f2 = f(0.65)
f3 = f(0.25)
```

Comment: There's only one `random` module and therefore only one seed. You'll have to create a `random.Random(seed)` object for each function.

Comment: Seeding a bunch of random number generators with the same seed is not very random.

Comment: @rici That's exactly my concern.

Comment: @Rawing That's why I'm importing random in the decorator, not out of it. No help?

Comment: But why do you feel the need to have multiple PRNG streams? All your generators can happily share a single PRNG, no?

Comment: Really, you do **not** have a decorator. A decorator is a  factory function that takes a function as an argument. Yours doesn't. Please don't call it a decorator, that only will mislead people searching for issues with actual decorators.

Comment: @rici You are right. As a matter of fact, the numbers are indeed random and they don't share the same random seed. I asked is because I didn't understand how it worked and was worried that f1, f2 and f3 would have the same seed and therefore produce correlated results.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Right. A decorator is about functions and this is a closure.

Comment: @Maxareo: Decorators use closures too; the defining characteristic of a decorator is that they only take a function object as input, returning a replacement (or the original). That way you can then use `@decorator` to decorate another function object.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This is a topic I'll go back to do more homework about. Thanks for the clarifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass in a seed to the *global random object* each time you call `f()`, because all top-level functions in the `random` module feed into a singleton object. This means that by the time `f3` is created, the seeds set in `f2` and `f1` have been superseded, the seeds are *not* independent from the global random object. Importing `random` again for each `f()` call does not give you a new state, as really only binds names anew each time once the module object itself is loaded (only on the first import).

If you want to have a seeded random generator *per function*, you need to create individual `random.Random()` instances:

```
import random
import time

def f(p):
    seeded_random = random.Random(time.time())
    def g():
        return 1 if seeded_random.random() < p else 0
    return g
```

From the [`random` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.Random):

> The functions supplied by this module are actually bound methods of a hidden instance of the `random.Random` class. You can instantiate your own instances of `Random` to get generators that don’t share state.

Comment: Are you saying f1, f2, f3 have the same random seed at the end? Suppose I only return random.random() in function g, then I would see the same values from f1, f2 and f3? A bit confused, please help make further clarification. Thanks.

Comment: @Maxareo: no, you won't see the same values. But in your code, `f1`, `f2` and `f3` all use a single global `Random()` object. You tell that one object to use a new seed three times, which simply means you discard whatever state was set for the first two calls.

Comment: @Maxareo: after that, `f1`, `f2` and `f3` produce random numbers from that one global `Random()` object seeded to the last call. That means they'll produce values in the same sequence as if you used one `random.Random()` object with the same seed as that last `random.seed()` call.

Comment: @Maxareo: those numbers are still pseudorandom. If you took a `foo = random.Random(seed_foo)` object, then called `foo.random()` a number of times, the values that that produces can be re-created exactly by using the exact same seed again in a different `random.Random()` object. Your `f1`, `f2` and `f3` simply draw from that sequence together, they are not backed by independent `random.Random()` objects. Their state is connected.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. These are indeed helpful. The part that is puzzling me is the modules are imported inside the function and how is the random seed related to the function g? When f1, f2 and f3 are created, they don't have their own random seed? Besides, I tried a little example importing the random module inside a toy function, run the toy function and called random.random() in the global namespace, but didn't work.

Comment: @Maxareo: importing does two things: 1. If not yet loaded, loads the module from disk, creating a `sys.modules[...]` entry. 2. binds names, either directly pointing to the module object (`import module` or `import module as newname`), or to attributes of the module object (`from module import attributename or `from module import attributename as newname`). Binding names produces new names *in the current scope*. So importing in a function adds local names, not globals.

Comment: @Maxareo: `def somefunction(): import random` binds the name `random` in the function scope. You could have done `random = 'foobar'` in the function and that'd also creates a local name, not a global.

Comment: This is just getting more and more interesting. The reason I'm asking is if random is imported in the function in the local scope, why did you say the functions f1, f2 and f3 share the same global random object?

Comment: @Maxareo: because the `sys.modules['random']` module object owns a singleton `Random` object. Each `random` name in the `g` namespace is just a reference to that one object.

Comment: @Maxareo: again, all that `import random` does is bind a local name. Names in Python are references to objects on the heap, using `import random` does not create a copy.

Comment: Dear Martijn, could you please write a toy example below explaining everything? I wanted to do some experiments but didn't know where to start since I don't have the concepts as you do about this area. Thanks.

Comment: @Maxareo: sorry, no, that's too broad. I do have a day-job too ;-)